# Upgrading from AWX 1.0.6 to 1.0.7

Tags: ansible-awx

How does everyone feel about awx 1.0.7? And the upgrade process?

I tried to upgrade from 106 to 107 and then move my data between a 106 machine and the new 107 server. I did this with tower-cli.

I found that tower-cli 3.2.1 works with awx 106, but not with 107. Yet, tower-cli 3.3.x works with awx 107, but has issues with awx 106. This means that I could not successfully transfer my data from the 106 server to the 107 server.

Furthermore, I connected my 107 server to the same database as my 106 server as the next thing to try. Low and behold, it screwd up the database - I got errors when trying to run my jobs in awx 106 server! Thankfully there were backups of the database that I could use that predated that stupid awx 107 upgrade debacle.

If anyone wants to have a try at upgrading, just remember to take shapshots/backups of your database, just in case. And let me know how it goes!

Answer (score 0):

My way:

```
    1.  BackUp
    2.  Remember all you credentials
    3.  Export data
    4.  Manually manipulation on exported data (add users and groups attributes)
    5.  Make fresh AWX install 
    6.  Import data
    7.  Restore source code credentials
    8.   Repeat import data
```

My envelopment:
 Awx 1.6.0.32 run in docker. Use docker-compose.
 Tower CLI 3.3.0
I upgrade to AWX to 1.0.7.2

First try standard and simplify method using docker-compose –

```
docker-compose pull && docker-compose up --force-recreate
```

This case is NOT work for me, db migration had many errors.
I use migration. https://github.com/ansible/awx/blob/devel/DATA_MIGRATION.md

```
tower-cli receive --all > assets.json
```

In my envelopment, export all assets work not correctly. Users and Inventory groups data is cut.  I restore it in asset file manually. And I had to remember all my credentials. This is simply for me, I have less 10 credentials.
After export clone git repository, stop and remove docker container and images, edit inventory file(installer/inventory) for my needs and make fresh install AWX 1.0.7.X.
Next step import. Before import I clear all data in new installation

```
tower-cli empty –all
```

After first import i had many errors because credentials(for source control) not import. Log in to fresh AWX restore all credentials and repeat import. After this actions all projects, inventories and jobs imports correctly.